# Rspec: Can't understand "and_raise" method

Tags: rspec

Here is my code:

```
account_double.should_receive(:withdraw).and_raise
```

I get the output:

```
1) Statement uses the customer's name in the header
Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
Exception
# ./spec/codebreaker/test.rb:8:in `generate'
# ./spec/codebreaker/test.rb:20
# /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `inject'
```

It cannot find Exception. How could I get this test to pass?

I dont understand the picture

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding an argument to `and_raise` - either an `Exception` class or a string to pass to `RuntimeError`

From the docs:

> Tells the mock to raise an exception instead of returning a value.
>    may be any Exception class, an instance of
>   any Exception class, or a String (in which case a RuntimeError will be raised
>   with that String as its message).

```
account_double.should_receive(:withdraw).and_raise(Exception)
```

Comment: Why does this `and_raise` dump the error in the rspec logging? SHouldn't it fail internally and be handled by the application? I feel like that's what's being tested, yet I get a huge backtrace when I run a spec that expects or stubs a raise.